# Angular hide dirrective depending on action in another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new in angular and i'm looking for the best way to do what I want.

In my main page I have 2 directives, one is used to display a button (and maybe other stuff). And another used to display a kind of dialog box/menu.

Each directive has its own controller.

I want to show or hide the second directive when I click on the button in the first one.

I don't really know what are goods or wrong approaches. Should I use a service injected in both controller and set a variable with ng-show in the second directive? This solution doesn't really hide the directive because I need a div inside the directive to hide its content and isn't too much to use a service only for one boolean?

Should I use a kind of global variable (rootscope?) or inject the first controller inside the second one?

Or maybe use a third controller in my main page (used with a service?) or use only one controller for both directive?

Basically without directive I would probably used only one main controller for my whole page and set a variable.

Comment: I would probably do two way binding for your directive that displays a button with a model property on the controller scope you are using for your main page (usually whatever is handling ng-app. This model property could then be attached to the other directive declaration in your main page (e.g., ng-show=model.property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the first directive is just a kind of button used to display "something", and the second directive just a kind of popup waiting a boolean to be displayed. That's why I finally used a service containing a boolean with a getter and a setter to avoid any interaction beetween both controller.

My both controller use this service, the first one to set the value when we click on the element and the second controller provide just a visibility on the getter for my ng-show.

I don't know if it is the best way to do but I am satisfied for now.

Small example here (without directive but with same logic) :
http://codepen.io/dufaux/pen/dXMrPm

```
angular.module('myModule', []);

angular.module("myModule")
  .controller("ButtonCtrl", buttonCtrl)
  .controller("PopUpCtrl", popUpCtrl)
  .service("DisplayerService", displayerService);

//ButtonCtrl
buttonCtrl.$inject = ["DisplayerService", "$scope"];
function buttonCtrl(DisplayerService, $scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.display = function(){
     DisplayerService.setDisplay(!DisplayerService.getDisplay());
  }
}

//PopUpCtrl
popUpCtrl.$inject = ["DisplayerService"];
function popUpCtrl(DisplayerService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.displayable = function(){
    return DisplayerService.getDisplay();
  }
}

//Service
function displayerService(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.display = false;

  vm.setDisplay = function(value){
    vm.display = value;
  }

  vm.getDisplay = function(){
    return vm.display;
  }
}
```

--

```
<body data-ng-app="myModule">
    <div data-ng-controller="ButtonCtrl as btnCtrl" >
      <button data-ng-click="btnCtrl.display()">
        display
      </button>
    </div>
    [...]
    <div data-ng-controller="PopUpCtrl as popUpCtrl" >
      <div data-ng-show="popUpCtrl.displayable()">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```